# How to prepare SVG images for presentation in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, kml, svg

I have a collection of SVG vector images I need to display on a map, probably using OpenLayers/KML. Is there any way to convert a vector image from SVG to KML? Or would it make more sense just to use PNG?  I would prefer to use vectors because the images will be rotated and need to scale properly when zooming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SVG is a vector format (image is made on the fly by client software), you can check GDAL/Ogr utility **ogr2ogr**, I guess it can convert svg to kml.

Comment: Actually, it can't.

Comment: It is because svg driver is not compiled by default, if you want convert data from svg to kml you need to compile ogr2ogr with svg support. And currently, driver will only read SVG files that are the output from Cloudmade Vector Stream Server.